Java - Null safety through generic function execution
When dealing with nested Objects in Java -
Something like:
// bad code
game.getPlayer().getState().getPositionInfo().getCurrent().getX();

, it is not clear if a nested reference would return null resulting in a NullPointerException to be thrown.
My idea was to have one generic method which calls reference path down while checking for a null reference,
and instead of throwing the Exception, just return null.
Error handling is out of scope for this solution.
My minimum code example looks like this:
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Check 1: baseline - "normal" function mappings
        SAVE.TY_Baseline(b -> b.contains("a"), "aoiudssaiud"); // works

        // Check 2: nested types
        Team t = new Team(new Team(null));
        Team t1 = SAVE.TY_Chained(() -> t.getTeam(), z -> z.getTeam()); // does not compile

        // Check 3: String -> boolean -> String
        String g = "Hi !";
        // does not compile
        Team t2 = SAVE.TY_Chained(() -> g.contains("Hi"), b -> b ? "contained" : "not contained"); 
    }

    public static class Team {
        private Team t = null;
        public Team(Team t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
        public Team getTeam() {
            return t;
        }
    }

    public static interface SAVE {
        public static <A, B> B TY_Chained(Function<Void, A> first , Function<A, B> second) {
            A firstResult = first.apply(null);
            if (firstResult == null)
                return null;
            return second.apply(firstResult);
        }
        public static <A,B> B TY_Baseline(Function<A,B> oo, A in) {
            return oo.apply(in);
        }
    }
}


For check 1:
Everything turns out good, the function executes and the compiler recognizes the input as String and also accepts the function.
For check 2 and 3:
When chaining the functions, the compiler does not know which parameter type function "second" has and will not accept this method call.
Getting:
java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

Using OpenJDK V22 right now.

I thought that was one of the reasons for ther addition of class Optional. Did you consider using it?

Check out Kotlin and the "safe-null" operator - it does exactly what you want and is all JVM compatible: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-call-operator

You can use existing libraries like vavr.
If you willing to invent your own wheel you can at least get some inspiration from them.
You specific case is simple enough it can be solved without third party library. Just Optional from standard JDK.
Optional.ofNullable(game)
  .map(x->x.getPlayer())
  .map(x->x.getState())
  .map(x->x.getPositionInfo())
  .map(x->x.getCurrent())
  .map(x->x.getX())
  .orElse(null);


Check 2 and 3 are failing because you're providing first a function with zero parameters, when it is expecting a function with one. Change TY_CHAINED's signature:
public static <A, B> TY_CHAINED(Supplier<A> first, Function<A, B> second) {
  A firstResult = first.get();
  if (firstReslt == null) return null;
  return second.apply(firstResult);
}

A Function<Void, A> is not actually a function that takes zero arguments, but is instead a function that takes one argument that must be null (since null is the only valid value for the Void type).
Otherwise, I agree with talex, Optional.map() is best for null-chaining

Thanks, for my shitts solutions this works, also with more chains applied !
